# MDI Parent form

Tags: c#, windows, mdi

```
Form1 objForm1 = new Form1 ();
objForm1 .MdiParent = this;
objForm1 .Show();
```

This is my code to open MDI form . IF I open this page again, it appears again and again and so many windows opens. Can anybody help?

Comment: Every time you run this code you will see a new form,What exactly do you want?

Comment: I want it to never again open when I click to open. and if I close form it also reached at different location how it is possible to stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new form only if it is not already opened you can do this:

```
ShowFormIfNotOpen(this,typeof(Form1));

public static void ShowFormIfNotOpen(Form mainform,Type type)
    {
        foreach (Form item in mainform.MdiChildren)
            if (item.GetType() == type)
            {
                item.Activate();
                return;
            }

         Form form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;
        form.MdiParent = mainform;
        form.Show();
    }
```

**Update**

1)Add a public static bool field/property in your form    (IsAlreadyShown)

```
public static bool IsAlreadyShown { get; set; }
```

2)Set it to true in the constructor of the form

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     IsAlreadyShown = true;
 }
```

3)Call  ShowForm1(this);

```
public static void ShowForm1(Form parentForm)
    {
        if(Form1.IsAlreadyShown ==true)
                return;


        Form1 objForm1 = new Form1 ();
        objForm1 .MdiParent = parentForm;
        objForm1 .Show();
    }
```

Comment: good but if i close form  and again open then form reaches at different location

Answer (score 0):

What i have understand so far from your question, you want form1 to be MDI Container. if you want this,then simply set the property ISMdiContainer to be true.Now if you want this form Form1 to be set as parent of any form you can use your code

```
    FormAny objFormAny = new FormAny ();
    objFormAny .MdiParent = objForm1; // reference of MDI Container
    objFormAny .Show();
```